# Casting Numbers and Dates

Tags: c#, casting, operators

I am very new to Bitwise Shift Operators.

```
ulong unitDate = (((ulong)885478688974) << 32) + (ulong)20170111;
uint low = (uint)(unitDate & (ulong)uint.MaxValue);
uint high = (uint)(unitDate >> 32);
```

In Low variable, I am getting the `data =20170111` which is correct.

In the high variable, I am getting the value as `715425998` which is not correct. I should get the value `885478688974`

What I have tried:

With the below code, I am getting exact values in low and high variable. How to handle the data that is bigger than `4294967295`?

```
ulong unitDate = (((ulong)4294967295) << 32) + (ulong)20170111;
uint low = (uint)(unitDate & (ulong)uint.MaxValue);
uint high = (uint)(unitDate >> 32);
```

Comment: wasn't right-shift hardware dependent?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't fit, there is nothing you can do about that. If it has to store numbers that large, you must give it more than 32 bits. E: also `(uint)(unitDate & (ulong)uint.MaxValue)` is equivalent to just `(uint)unitDate`

Comment: Actually can you explain the real requirements? Putting 885478688974 and 20170111 together in an `ulong` isn't going to work, even cutting them down to the minimum number of bits, they'd take 40 and 25 bits respectively, but an `ulong` only has 64.

Comment: the data which i provided like 885478688974  and 20170111 is sample data ,we may receive data is more or less 885478688974  and same even applies for 20170111

Comment: How about using a BigInteger - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you really need though? Is this just a fun way to emulate a tuple (see the actual tuple)? Is it actually an integer defined by a low and high part, but the high part can be really big (see BigInteger)? Is it actually meant to be two halves of a 64bit ulong, but the example data is wrong?

Comment: This is how my  exact code looks like
 

ulong unitDate = (((ulong)unitID) << 32) + (ulong)localTimeStamp.Date; 
uinT unitID = (uint) (0xffffffff & (unitDate >> 32));     
uint localDate = (uint) (0xffffffff &  unitDate);

if my unitid is less than 4294967295 i am getting exact results but when if it more than 4294967295 i am not getting exact results in the unitid

Comment: Harold any suggestions to handle more than 64bit ?

Comment: It depends on what you need from it. If you just use it as key in a dictionary or hashset, `Tuple<ulong, uint>` is nice, but that would be really annoying if you actually do math with it.